# How does xpathselector affect the speed of scrapy crawl running?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using Scrapy crawler to crawl over 100k pages website.  The speed is the big concern in this case.  Today I noticed that `hxs.select('//*').re('something')` is way slower than `hxs.select('//script/text()').re('something')`.  Can any expert explain to me why?

As I understand, the crawler should download the entire page no matter what xpath selector I use.  So the xpath should not affect the speed much at all.

Thanks a lot for any tips.

Comment: how can I speed up the crawler running if I have to use hxs.select('//*').re('something'). because I do not know where is 'something' located on the page. or is there any better way to do the search instead of using select('//*')?

Comment: Surely you have *some* idea where it is? E.g., `hxs.select('/html/body').re('something')`. But if it can really be anywhere then just drop the `select`: `hxs.re('something')`

Comment: crawler is running faster after I drop the select. but I wonder why is this happening ? how come select make so big different? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with download speed.

XPath `//*` selects the entire page. XPath `//script/text()` selects only text inside script elements. So of course the second one is faster, because there is less text to search with the `re()` call!

Comment: Hi Francis, crawler is running faster after I drop the select. but I wonder why is this happening ? how does 'select' make so big different? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you might look for 'something' in the entire document, so you probably should still use `hxs.select('//*').re('something')`.

And about the speed question: the answer is that if you look for the word 'something' in a document which is 4k large, of course it will take longer then filtering the document for `text()` and after looking for that word within that text.

Answer (score 0):

XPath definitely has a role in crawler speed, crawler download the page, but Xpath process the Html that crawler downloaded. so if the page is big then xpath will take time to process whole Html.